# Is there an Objective-c regex replace with callback/C# MatchEvaluator equivalent?

Tags: objective-c, regex, replace, callback, nsregularexpression

I have a C# project I'm intending to port to Objective-C. From what I understand about Obj-C, it looks like there's a confusing variety of Regex options but I can't see anything about a way of doing a replace with callback.

I'm looking for something that is the equivalent of the C# MatchEvaluator delegate or PHP's preg_replace_callback. An example of what I want to do in C# is -

```
// change input so each word is followed a number showing how many letters it has

string inputString = "Hello, how are you today ?";
Regex theRegex = new Regex(@"\w+");

string outputString = theRegex.Replace(inputString, delegate (Match thisMatch){
   return thisMatch.Value + thisMatch.Value.Length;
});

// outputString is now 'Hello5, how3 are3 you3 today5 ?'
```

How could I do this in Objective-C ? In my actual situation the Regex has both lookahead and lookbehind assertions in it though, so any alternative involving finding the strings in advance and then doing a series of straight string replaces won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Foundation has a [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class (iOS4 and later), which may be useful to you.  From the docs:

> The fundamental matching method for
>   NSRegularExpression is a Block
>   iterator method that allows clients to
>   supply a Block object which will be
>   invoked each time the regular
>   expression matches a portion of the
>   target string. There are additional
>   convenience methods for returning all
>   the matches as an array, the total
>   number of matches, the first match,
>   and the range of the first match.

For example:

```
NSString *input = @"Hello, how are you today?";

// make a copy of the input string. we are going to edit this one as we iterate
NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithString:input];

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression 
                                regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\w+"
                                                     options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                       error:&error];

// keep track of how many additional characters we've added (1 per iteration)
__block NSUInteger count = 0;  

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:input
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

    // Note that Blocks in Objective C are basically closures
    // so they will keep a constant copy of variables that were in scope
    // when the block was declared
    // unless you prefix the variable with the __block qualifier

    // match.range is a C struct
    // match.range.location is the character offset of the match
    // match.range.length is the length of the match        

    NSString *matchedword = [input substringWithRange:match.range];

    // the matched word with the length appended
    NSString *new  = [matchedword stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", [matchedword length]];

    // every iteration, the output string is getting longer
    // so we need to adjust the range that we are editing
    NSRange newrange = NSMakeRange(match.range.location+count, match.range.length);
    [output replaceCharactersInRange:newrange withString:new];

    count++;
}];
NSLog(@"%@", output); //output: Hello5, how3 are3 you3 today5?
```

Comment: Is it also possible to tweak Swift's [`stringByReplacingMatches(in:options:range:withTemplate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1413740-stringbyreplacingmatches) like that?

Answer (score 3):

I modified atshum's code to make it a bit more flexible:

```
__block int prevEndPosition = 0;
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:text
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSRange r = {.location = prevEndPosition, .length = match.range.location - prevEndPosition};

    // Copy everything without modification between previous replacement and new one
    [output appendString:[text substringWithRange:r]]; 
    // Append string to be replaced
    [output appendString:@"REPLACED"];

    prevEndPosition = match.range.location + match.range.length;
}];

// Finalize string end
NSRange r = {.location = prevEndPosition, .length = [text length] - prevEndPosition};
[output appendString:[text substringWithRange:r]];
```

Seems to work for now (probably needs a bit more testing)